# Traveling Salesman On Boolean Matrix

Tags: shortest-path, traveling-salesman, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm looking for some advice on how to tackle this problem.
You're given a binary matrix of 1s and 0s, and the goal is to find the shortest path that visits every 1. 
For example: 
1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 
1 0 1 1 
0 0 0 1 
The shortest path (I think) to visit all ones is something like this:
**1 0 0** 0 
**0** 0 **1** 0 
**1** 0 **1 1** 
0 0 0 **1** 
In any case, I believe this is a traveling salesman type of problem or possibly a minimum spanning tree. However, I'm completely unsure how to even get started. This is not a typical graph search as you technically don't have neighbors or costs, and there is no predefined start node; you can start or end at any position. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a TSP. Define the set of nodes `V` as the set of 1s in the matrix. Define the distance `d(i,j)` between any `i` and `j` in `V` as the distance within the matrix. If I'm understanding your example correctly, you are allowed to "move" only vertically or horizontally in the matrix. So `d(i,j) = |i_x - j_x| + |i_y - j_y|`, where `(i_x,i_y)` are the coordinates (row and column number) of node `i`, and similarly for `j`. (This is also called Manhattan metric, rectilinear metric, or L1 norm.)

It seems like you want a path rather than a cycle -- start anywhere and end anywhere. Classical TSP assumes you start and end at the same node. Simple fix: Create a dummy node and set the distance to/from the dummy node from/to any other node to 0. Then just ignore the edges to/from the dummy node in the optimal TSP tour.